# Hello everybody,

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, qt, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to write a program that should move an X in a defined frame. For this purpose, a while loop should start with a KeyPress and stop with a KeyReleases.

I only found the multithreading or multiprocessing methods on the Internet to do that simultaneously. The multithreading itself works for a certain amount of time (always differently) and then I get various error messages or the program freezes completely.

Often it is interrupted by signal 11 sigsegv.

The code is:

```
# GLOBAL
import faulthandler; faulthandler.enable()
import sys
import time
import requests

from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key
from qtpy import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from ui.mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

# Globale Variablen:
PAN = 250
TILT = 150
SPEED = 1
TIME = 0.01
KEYS = []
THREADS = 0
DIRECTION = []

# HTTP SECTION


payload = {"name": "MK"}
r = requests.get("https://httpbin.org/get", params=payload)
print(r.status_code)

# BUILD GUI
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()  # Laden des Style Frames
        self.ui.setupUi(self)  # Funktion aus Ui_MainWindow ausführen (Fenster zeichnen)
        self.ui.tilt.setText(str(TILT))
        self.ui.pan.setText(str(PAN))
        self.ui.speed.setText(str(SPEED))

        ## Button Funktionsaufrufe:
        self.thread = {}
        self.ui.btnUp.clicked.connect(self.moveUP)
        self.ui.btnDown.clicked.connect(self.moveDOWN)
        self.ui.btnLeft.clicked.connect(self.moveLEFT)
        self.ui.btnRight.clicked.connect(self.moveRIGHT)
        self.ui.btnCenter.clicked.connect(self.stop_worker)

        self.ui.speed.textChanged.connect(self.setSpeed)

    # Funktion zum bewegen über die Buttons 

    def startUp(self):
        self.thread[1] = ThreadClass(parent=None, index=1)
        self.thread[1].start()
        self.thread[1].any_signal.connect(self.my_function)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.thread[1].stop()
        print('init thread 1 on startup')
        self.thread[2] = ThreadClass(parent=None, index=2)
        self.thread[2].start()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.thread[2].stop()
        print('init thread 2 on startup')
        self.thread[3] = ThreadClass(parent=None, index=3)
        self.thread[3].start()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.thread[3].stop()
        print('init thread 3 on startup')
        self.thread[4] = ThreadClass(parent=None, index=4)
        self.thread[4].start()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.thread[4].stop()
        print('init thread 4 on startup')
        print('... \n \n \n')

        print('Status = Ready:')
        print('Keys = ', KEYS)

    def moveUP(self):
        if bool(self.thread[2].isRunning()):
            self.stopDOWN()
        self.thread[1] = ThreadClass(parent=None, index=1)
        self.thread[1].start()
        self.thread[1].any_signal.connect(self.my_function)
        #self.ui.btnUp.setEnabled(False)

    def moveDOWN(self):
        # global DIRECTION
        # DIRECTION.append('Down')
        self.thread[2] = ThreadClass(parent=None, index=2)
        self.thread[2].start()
        self.thread[2].any_signal.connect(self.my_function)
        #self.ui.btnDown.setEnabled(False)

    def moveLEFT(self):
        # global DIRECTION
        # DIRECTION.append('Left')
        if bool(self.thread[4].isRunning()):
            self.stopRIGHT()
        self.thread[3] = ThreadClass(parent=None, index=3)
        self.thread[3].start()
        self.thread[3].any_signal.connect(self.my_function)
        #self.ui.btnLeft.setEnabled(False)

    def moveRIGHT(self):
        # global DIRECTION
        # DIRECTION.append('Right')
        self.thread[4] = ThreadClass(parent=None, index=4)
        self.thread[4].start()
        self.thread[4].any_signal.connect(self.my_function)
        #self.ui.btnRight.setEnabled(False)

    def stopUP(self):
        global KEYS
        if bool(self.thread[1].isRunning()):
            self.thread[1].stop()
            #self.ui.btnUp.setEnabled(True)
            KEYS.remove(Key.up)
        # DIRECTION.remove('Up')

    def stopDOWN(self):
        global KEYS
        if bool(self.thread[2].isRunning()):
            self.thread[2].stop()
            #self.ui.btnDown.setEnabled(True)
            KEYS.remove(Key.down)

        # DIRECTION.remove('Down')

    def stopLEFT(self):
        global KEYS
        if bool(self.thread[3].isRunning()):
            self.thread[3].stop()
            #self.ui.btnLeft.setEnabled(True)
            KEYS.remove(Key.left)
        # DIRECTION.remove('Left')

    def stopRIGHT(self):
        global KEYS
        if bool(self.thread[4].isRunning()):
            self.thread[4].stop()
            #self.ui.btnRight.setEnabled(True)
            KEYS.remove(Key.right)
        # DIRECTION.remove('Right')

    def stop_worker(self):
        global DIRECTION

        if 'Up' in DIRECTION:
            self.thread[1].stop()
            #self.ui.btnUp.setEnabled(True)
            DIRECTION.remove('Up')

        if 'Down' in DIRECTION:
            self.thread[2].stop()
            #self.ui.btnDown.setEnabled(True)
            DIRECTION.remove('Down')

        if 'Left' in DIRECTION:
            self.thread[3].stop()
            #self.ui.btnLeft.setEnabled(True)

        if 'Right' in DIRECTION:
            self.thread[4].stop()
            #self.ui.btnRight.setEnabled(True)
            DIRECTION.remove('Right')

    def my_function(self, counter):
        global KEYS
        cnt = counter
        index = self.sender().index
        if index == 1:
            print(cnt)

    def setSpeed(self):
        global SPEED
        if self.ui.speed.text():
            SPEED = int(self.ui.speed.text())

    # Funktion zum bewegen über die Tasten 
    def on_press(key):
        global KEYS
        if key not in KEYS:
            if key == Key.up:
                MainWindow.moveUP(window)
                KEYS.append(key)
                print('added: ' + str(key))
            if key == Key.down:
                if Key.up in KEYS:
                    pass
                else:
                    MainWindow.moveDOWN(window)
                    KEYS.append(key)
                    print('added: ' + str(key))

            if key == Key.left:
                MainWindow.moveLEFT(window)
                KEYS.append(key)
                print('added: ' + str(key))
            if key == Key.right:
                if Key.left in KEYS:
                    pass
                else:
                    MainWindow.moveRIGHT(window)
                    KEYS.append(key)
                    print('added: ' + str(key))

    def on_release(key):
        global KEYS
        if key in KEYS:
            if key == Key.up and Key.up in KEYS:
                MainWindow.stopUP(window)
            if key == Key.down and Key.down in KEYS:
                MainWindow.stopDOWN(window)
            if key == Key.left and Key.left in KEYS:
                MainWindow.stopLEFT(window)
            if key == Key.right and Key.right in KEYS:
                MainWindow.stopRIGHT(window)
        print(KEYS)
        if key == Key.esc:
            MainWindow.stop_worker(window)

    # Collect events until released
    listener = keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release)
    listener.start()


class ThreadClass(QtCore.QThread):
    any_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None, index=0):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.index = index
        self.is_running = True

    def run(self):
        global TILT
        global PAN
        global TIME
        global SPEED
        print('Starting thread...', self.index)
        i = self.index
        while (True):
            if i == 1:
                if TILT <= 0:
                    pass
                else:
                    TILT -= SPEED
                    window.ui.tilt.setText(str(TILT))
                    window.ui.target.setGeometry(PAN, TILT, 10, 16)
                    # print("T", TILT)
                time.sleep(TIME)

            if i == 2:
                if TILT >= 301:
                    pass
                else:
                    TILT += SPEED
                    window.ui.tilt.setText(str(TILT))
                    window.ui.target.setGeometry(PAN, TILT, 10, 16)
                    # print('T', TILT)
                time.sleep(TIME)

            if i == 3:
                if PAN <= 0:
                    pass
                else:
                    PAN -= SPEED
                    window.ui.pan.setText(str(PAN))
                    window.ui.target.setGeometry(PAN, TILT, 10, 16)
                    # print("P", PAN)
                time.sleep(TIME)

            if i == 4:
                if PAN >= 500:
                    pass
                else:
                    PAN += SPEED
                    window.ui.pan.setText(str(PAN))
                    window.ui.target.setGeometry(PAN, TILT, 10, 16)
                    # print("P", PAN)
                time.sleep(TIME)

    def stop(self):
        self.is_running = False
        print('Stopping thread...', self.index)
        self.terminate()


window = MainWindow()

window.show()
window.startUp()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am currently programming in PyCharm on a MacBook with OS 12.6.

Comment: Hi Markus, I see you are new in here. Please specify your problem in the header. Hello Everybody is not explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't read all your code, but you are trying to access the GUI from a thread which is not the main thread. This is illegal and will result in crashes sooner or later.

Comment: Hello,
Please excuse me, I'm very new in programming. I will try it.
Thank you very much

Comment: Re, "I'm very new in programming." Learning about threads is _not_ a good place to start. Multi-threaded code has subtle tricks that are hard to get right, and hard to debug when you get them wrong. It can be frustrating, and without anybody to guide you it could discourage you from trying to learn more. P.S., There is no need for you to create threads in order to animate moving objects on the screen that respond to user input. You can use "timers" for that. (Sorry to say though, I personally, do not know Qt well enough to show you how.)